# How do I make excel to recognize year values in the format YYYY as a year date and not see the values as numbers and convert it to a different year?

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I'm trying to convert a column which contains year values to a date type that excel will recognize. The column contains values such as 2004, 2018, 2014 etc. But excel reads this year values as numbers and returns the year those numbers represents. For instance, it returns 2004 as 1905.

I have tried to use the "Format Cells" and "Text" category to convert the cell values to text in the YYYY format. Then, use the DateValue() function to convert it to a date type.

I expected the Datevalue function to return the year values[image: Screenshot of the]

Comment: if the cell contains #2004, then take the rightmost 4 characters like so: "=right(CP1,4)*1". Then 2004 will be a number and you can work with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want excel to treat a cell's value as a date, it has to be an actual date.

If you intend to show only the year (YYYY) in a date cell, it has to be in the first place a valid full date - with day and month.

so for your example, you can use the function DATE(),
by passing the selected year, and you can just put 1 in month and day parameters.
For example: `=DATE(A1, 1, 1)` assuming A1 contains a year value.

Then you'll have a cell which contain a valid date, for example 01.01.2004,
and you'll be able to format it using Date formats, for example "YYYY"

Answer (score 0):

In Excel date is stored as a number. Number 1 converted to date gives 1900 01 01. Number 2004 converted to date gives 1905 06 26 and if you format it as `"yyyy"` it shows only year 1905.
Just a year itself without a month and a day can't be recognized as a date and it is not clear why do you want that.

Answer (score -1):

what you have to do is to use a function:
=text(CP1, "YYY"), It'll help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).